# JQuery ready function not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i enqueue js file in worpress and file is loaded and working with native js code but jQuery ready not working

```
 alert('working');  
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
   alert('not working');  
});
```

the site url
http://typingbooster.expotech.co.in/
please view source the file custom.js

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: no, the alert box is appearing (the working one), but the alert box (not working) one not executing, i am getting confuse why,, anything within ready function not executing,,

Comment: Is Jquery included before your script?

Comment: Is this fixed ?? Its common etiquette here at SOF to post back the status of the issue and accept/upvote answers if they helped you.

Answer (score 1):

In wordPress environment, use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that jQuery has been enqueue'd?  You can ensure it is by adding it to your functions.php:

```js
add_action('init', 'load_jquery_scripts', 0);
function load_jquery_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    alert('works');
});
```

Hope this will work for you!